# ios - Can crop photo vertical but not horizontal

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, crop, cgrect

I have a `UIScrollView` with a `UIImageView` inside of it. For this part of my app, the user can select photos from their camera roll and scale and crop them.

I have successfully made the user be able select different photos, then zoom in and out & pan around the image. Also, the user can zoom out to make the image centre vertically or horizontally depending on if the image is portrait or landscape.

The problem is, I try to then crop the photo from the visible rect in the scroll view to a new image, however its only working for portrait photos.

Here is an example of it working then not working:

**Here is a portrait image that is zoomed out to fit the screen:**

[image]

**Next, I zoom in the image so there is no black space.**

[image]

**Finally, I crop the photo and you can see it crops perfectly in the top left hand corner.**

[image]

**However, for some reason when I try to do this with a landscape image the cropping messes up?! Here is an example of it not working.**

**Here is a zoomed out landscape image.**

[image]

**Next, I zoom in so there is no black space left. Notice how I zoomed in specifically so there is no physical boarder of the white board visible in the photo.**

[image]

**Now, I crop the photo just like before and it doesn't crop it properly. Notice how in the top left hand corner the image is different from before. It appears to have been zoomed out and you can see more of the bottom of the white board.**

[image]

I need to figure out why this is happening and how to fix it.

Here is the exact code I use to crop the photo from the `UIScrollView`.

```
    //Get the scale
    float scale = 1.0f/_libraryScrollView.zoomScale;

    //Create a new rect
    CGRect visibleRect;
    visibleRect.origin.x = _libraryScrollView.contentOffset.x * scale;
    visibleRect.origin.y = _libraryScrollView.contentOffset.y * scale;
    visibleRect.size.width = _libraryScrollView.bounds.size.width * scale;
    visibleRect.size.height = _libraryScrollView.bounds.size.height * scale;

    //Get the source image
    UIImage *src = libraryPreviewImageView.image;

    //Create the new cropped image with the rect
    CGImageRef cr = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(src.CGImage, visibleRect);
    UIImage *finalImage = [[UIImage alloc]initWithCGImage:cr];

    //Set the new image to the preview image view
    self.imagePreviewView.image = finalImage;
```

This code works for portrait images but doesn't work for landscape images as shown above in the examples. Is this error to do with my cropping code or is it to do with something else?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I had no idea what was the problem but trying to use maths to crop an image from a scroll view is extremely difficult!

I found a really easy way and that is to take a screen shot of the visible content in the scroll view, its as easy as this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_libraryScrollView.bounds.size, YES, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
CGPoint offset = _libraryScrollView.contentOffset;
CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), -offset.x, -offset.y);
[_libraryScrollView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

//Set the new image to the preview image view
self.imagePreviewView.image = finalImage;
```

I really hope this answer can help other people out too!